# Store info in an excel file from telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to program a telegram bot that collects information from people who want to join a project and stores this information in an excel file

```
from typing import NoReturn
from time import sleep
from email import *
from tkinter import*
from turtle import *
from telegram import*
import telegram
from telegram.ext import*
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
from telegram.error import NetworkError, Unauthorized
print('bot started....')
wb=''
full_name=''
birth_date=''
phone=''
ONE=""
TWO=""
THREE=''
x=0
FIRST=''
SECOND=''

users = {
    # user_id:{'key':'value'}
}

UPDATE_ID = None


def echo (bot: telegram.Bot) -> None:
    """Echo the message the user sent."""
    global UPDATE_ID
    for update in bot.get_updates(offset=UPDATE_ID, timeout=10):
       UPDATE_ID = update.update_id + 1
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) :
        global UPDATE_ID
        
        
        if not UPDATE_ID in users:
         users[UPDATE_ID] = {}
        keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="I want to join", callback_data='one')]]
    
    
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text(text="Welcome", reply_markup=reply_markup)
def Aplly(update, context):

        global  full_name, birth_date, phone       
        full_name=''
        birth_date=''
        phone=''
        x=0
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer()
        query.message.reply_text(text='Full name')
        
        
def handlmsg(update, context):
         global x, full_name, birth_date, phone, chat_idd,university,College,year,email,address,Study_major,reasons

         
         if x==0:
          full_name={'full_name':update.message.text}
          update.message.reply_text(text="birth day")

         if x ==1:
          
          birth_date={'birth_date':update.message.text}
          update.message.reply_text(text="Phone")
    
         
         if x ==2:
          phone=update.message.text
          update.message.reply_text(text="completed...")
          print(full_name)
          print(birth_date)
          print(phone)
          keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Confirm", callback_data='two')],
           [InlineKeyboardButton(text="to retreat", callback_data='three')]]
          reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
          update.message.reply_text(text="Confirm", reply_markup=reply_markup)   
         
    
         return SECOND

def save(update,context):
         global UPDATE_ID,wb
         query = update.callback_query

         query.answer()

         query.edit_message_text(text="Done")
   
         header =['full name', 'birth date', 'phone','chadt_id']
         data = [full_name,birth_date, phone, UPDATE_ID]
         wb = xl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')

         page = wb.active
         page.title = 'companies'
         page.append(header) 
         companies = [data]

         for info in companies:
           page.append(info)
         wb.save('sample12.xlsx')

         wb = xl.load_workbook('sample12.xlsx')
         page = wb.active
   
         sheet = wb['companies'] 
     

         for i in range(1,sheet.max_row+1):
          cell1=sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value
          x=int(UPDATE_ID)
          if x==cell1:
           page.delete_rows(i)

         wb.save('sample112.xlsx') 
         doc_file = open('sample112.xlsx', 'rb')
         return context.bot.send_document(844534481, doc_file)
       
def main() -> NoReturn:
 """Run the bot."""
 updater = Updater('Tokn', use_context=True)      
    
 global UPDATE_ID
        
 bot = telegram.Bot('tokn')

 try:
     UPDATE_ID = bot.get_updates()[0].update_id
 except IndexError:
           UPDATE_ID = None



 while True:
     try:
      echo(bot)
     except NetworkError:
            sleep(1)
     except Unauthorized:

      UPDATE_ID += 1
    

     updater = Updater('Tokn', use_context=True)
     updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
     updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handlmsg))
     conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
         entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
         states={
            FIRST: [updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(Aplly, pattern='one'))],
            SECOND: [updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(save, pattern='two')),
            updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(Aplly, pattern='three'))]},
         fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)],)


     updater.start_polling()

     updater.idle()

main()
```

The problem occurs when two people want to use the bot at the same time, it treats them as one person
It stores their data in the same field
I think i need to use a dictionary but I didn't know how to relate it to the if and the counter

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you want to use dict to save user's state, you can create another one dict in the main dict, where user_id = key, and a new dict = value.
I mean something like that:

```
STATES = {}

user_id = 123

STATES[user_id] = {}

STATES[user_id]['name'] = name
STATES[user_id]['action'] = action_name
```

Or you also can google something like that: transitions machine python